# Faster replace method

Tags: python, string

I have written a function, which takes aligned DNA sequences and replaces "-" with "Z" if the "-" is both preceded and followed by other bases. The goal is to make those bases a "Z" so I can differentiate unsequenced regions of a genome from insertions/deletions. Here's the function:

```
  def find_insertion_deletion(sequence):
    pattern = r'[A-Z]+-+(?=[A-Z]+)'
    new_sequence = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace('-', 'Z'), sequence)
    return new_sequence
```

This is obviously using regex to find the pattern and then make the replacements. He's an example of how it works.

```
sequence = '-----------AGCATCGACGTCTAGTAC---CGTACGTA--CGTACGTAGCTA-GCTAGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGCA---------------'
new_sequence = find_insertion_deletion(sequence)
```

output:

```
new_sequence = '-----------AGCATCGACGTCTAGTACZZZCGTACGTAZZCGTACGTAGCTAZGCTAGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGCA---------------'
```

It works exactly how I want it to, but it's very slow when running this on many sequences in an alignment. Is there a way I can speed this up by a significant amount? I assumed regex would be the fastest way, but maybe there's another way I'm not aware of..

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this function is the bottleneck of the performance?

Comment: Yes. This is a part of a larger pipeline I've built to analyze genomic sequences, but I do have multiple progress bars and print statements to let the user know where they are in the progress. This is the function that's adding a lot of time

Comment: Wiktor, I just tried that and it does seem to speed it up quite a bit! Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmm, as far as I saw, "everyone" is at most me (if you consider my answer as suggesting that). Why remove those original tags? They looked proper and useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your example is representative, i.e., that you simply want to replace all hyphens except those at the start and at the end. This uses basic string functions, which are much faster:

```
def find_insertion_deletion(sequence):
    stripped = sequence.strip('-')
    if not stripped:
        return sequence
    start = sequence.index(stripped[0])
    end = len(sequence) - start - len(stripped)
    return '-' * start + stripped.replace('-', 'Z') + '-' * end
```

Or:

```
def find_insertion_deletion(sequence):
    lstripped = sequence.lstrip('-')
    start = len(sequence) - len(lstripped)
    stripped = lstripped.rstrip('-')
    end = len(lstripped) - len(stripped)
    return '-' * start + stripped.replace('-', 'Z') + '-' * end
```

**Benchmarks**

With your example sequence:

```
   80.5 us  original
   20.5 us  Wiktor_1
   14.4 us  Wiktor_2
    3.6 us  Kelly_1
    3.3 us  Kelly_2
```

With a longer sequence (`sequence *= 1000`):

```
 5931.9 us  original
20896.0 us  Wiktor_1
 7498.8 us  Wiktor_2
  150.5 us  Kelly_1
  160.9 us  Kelly_2
```

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
import re
import regex

def original(sequence):
    pattern = r'[A-Z]+-+(?=[A-Z]+)'
    new_sequence = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group().replace('-', 'Z'), sequence)
    return new_sequence

def Wiktor_1(sequence):
    return regex.sub(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|[A-Z](?=-+[A-Z]))\K-', 'Z', sequence)

def Wiktor_2(sequence):
    return re.sub(r'\b-+\b', lambda x: x.group().replace('-', 'Z'), sequence)

def Kelly_1(sequence):
    stripped = sequence.strip('-')
    if not stripped:
        return sequence
    start = sequence.index(stripped[0])
    end = len(sequence) - start - len(stripped)
    return '-' * start + stripped.replace('-', 'Z') + '-' * end

def Kelly_2(sequence):
    lstripped = sequence.lstrip('-')
    start = len(sequence) - len(lstripped)
    stripped = lstripped.rstrip('-')
    end = len(lstripped) - len(stripped)
    return '-' * start + stripped.replace('-', 'Z') + '-' * end

funcs = original, Wiktor_1, Wiktor_2, Kelly_1, Kelly_2

sequence = '-----------AGCATCGACGTCTAGTAC---CGTACGTA--CGTACGTAGCTA-GCTAGCTAGCTGATCGATGCTAGCA---------------'
sequence *= 1   # or 1000 with number = 10**2
number = 10**5

expect = original(sequence)
for func in funcs:
    print(func(sequence) == expect, func.__name__)

for _ in range(3):
    print()
    for func in funcs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(sequence), number=number)) / number
        print('%7.1f us ' % (t * 1e6), func.__name__)
```

Comment: thank you! This is perfect. I didn't realize how much faster basic string functions would be.